# jquery auto complete how php file fetch textbox value?

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on an autocomplete feature using jQuery and PHP. Everything is working fine but I can't understand how the PHP file should fetch the value of the textbox (because I have not posted the Form)

```
$("#auto_complete").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

require('connection.php');

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query="SELECT b_type FROM b_details WHERE b_type LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data[] = $row['b_type'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: 1. You never pass the `term` `GET` variable to your `search.php` file. Look at the `data` property of the `autocomplete` plugin. 2. Don't use `mysql_*`; those functions are now deprecated and your code won't be future-proof. Finally, please PLEASE learn about SQL injection! Check out PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: thanks but i have write some php function using mysql_* in my previous applications .  can it may be problematic in feature

Comment: ok i have changed my code